# ImportError: No module named comments Django1.8

Tags: django

I'm trying to use django-comments-xtd, and when I configure everything I get this error, ImportError: No module named comments
I'm using django 1.8, I did pip install django-cotnrib-comments and set     'django_comments', to my installed app. What am I doing wrong?

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (

    'django_comments',
    'django_comments_xtd',)

Traceback:
:
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  .2/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  .2/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  .2/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  .2/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  .2/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-pack 119, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named comments
```

Comment: Please post your code and the error message and trace. Also, post the version numbers as returned by the code itself.

Comment: @ray, is my step right? do you have any experience with django-comments? regardless of that, I posted what you requested

Comment: Does it also fail if you try to import the module from the django shell? I don't have experience with the `django-comments` module in particular, but I do have experience with Python and Django.

Comment: The django docs show that this was deprecated back in version [1.6](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/comments/).There're no doc pages in [1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/comments/). I don't think you should be trying to use this module.

Comment: Are you trying to use `django-comments-xtd` or `django-contrib-comments`? These are two separate packages. ray pointed out `django-contrib-comments` is deprecated, but if you want to use `django-comments-xtd`, please try `pip install django-comments-xtd`, according to the [docs](https://django-comments-xtd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#installation)